# Drag drop to file input div jquery

Tags: jquery, image, file, input, drag-and-drop

I got a file input which is connected to a button. So when the div is clicked, the hidden file input is also clicked. When the file(image) is sent to the site, it is implemented as the button background.

Html

```
<input type='file' id='form_file' onchange="readURL(event)" accept="image/*"/>
<button id="form_button"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i></button>
```

Jquery

```
$("#form_button").click(function() {
    $("#form_file").click();
    return false;
})
function readURL(event){
    var getImagePath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    $('#form_button').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImagePath + ')');
}
```

So my problem is that I can't drop files into the button. Does anyone know how I can make the button droppable?
Thank you.